# Google Cloud Promote

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I download the example hello-world project and paste these files in my directory and execute:

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote
```

it uploads fine, but once I start adding my own files and modifying the ones it gives us and then try to execute

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote
```

it gives me this error.  I am not positive this is actually tied to the modification of files, but does anyone know how to fix this?

```
(gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Not enough VMs ready (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying). Version: 20151215t220456.389294541277182349
```

I have searched the web for this and none of the posts have resolutions.

**EDIT:**

This is inthe app.yaml file, should I be removing this line? (I did add libraries to it)

```
# Temporary setting to keep gcloud from uploading node_modules
skip_files:
 - ^node_modules$
```

Comment: Delete the previous deployed version and VMs, and try to deploy your latest files again?

Comment: This does not help.  Is it truly a problem with the new files I am deploying?  When I switch directories back to the helloworldtest and try to upload it works fine, go back to my dir and try to promote.  I get that error^^